# Is there a symetrical design pattern so member classes can have pointers to eachother?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a what is more of a  design question. I have a class, say class S, that has two member classes, P and C. Class P needs to call member functions from class C and class P needs to call member functions from C.

Right now the way I deal with this has been to first create C and pass it to P and in turn make P static so its member functions can be accessed from C. ( It is possible that later on I will have an array of C classes, but I will always have one P – which is why I can make it static)

My question is, is there a better way to set this up? I don’t like making P static -  Ideally, I’d like C and P  to have pointers to each other but how?

Some over simplified code is attached.

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

class C;

class P {
   C *c;
   P (C *x ): c(x)  {};

 public:
    static P *p;
    static P *get_P(C *x) { if (!p) { p= new P(x);}; return p;};
    static P *get_P () { return p;}

    void P_function ();
    void P_other ();
};

class C {
  public:
    C ()  {};
    void C_function ()
    {
      std::cout << "in C_funtion\n";
    }
    void C_other ()
    {
      P::get_P()->P_function();
    }
};

void P::P_other ()
{
  c->C_function();
}

void P::P_function ()
{
  std::cout << "in P_funtion\n";
}

class S {
  public:
  C c;

  S()
  {
     P::get_P(&c);
  };
};

P* P::p = NULL;

int main ()
{
  S s;

  s.c.C_other();
  P::get_P()->P_other();
```

}

Comment: Maybe you should ask yourself if this circular dependency is really necessary. There might be situations in which they are but in my opinion they are quite seldom.

Answer (score 2):

In your header files make no include to the other class, only a forward declaration, and use pointers:

```
// C.h
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H
class P;

class C 
{
     P *p;
public: 
     C (P *x ); 
     // *** no inline implementation of methods calling P methods here!!
}
#endif
```

The same do for P, but don't pass the C object via constructor, pass it by a separate method into the P object (to avoid the obvious hen-or-egg problem when constructing the two objects).

```
// P.h
#ifndef P_H
#define P_H
class C;

class P 
{
     C *c;
public: 
     P (); 
     void SetC(C *x){c=x;}
}
#endif
```

In your CPP files, include C.h in P.cpp and P.h in C.cpp, then you can call methods of P in C and vice versa.

Now in your class S, first create a P object, then create a C object passing the P object to it, and finally pass the C object into P by using `SetC`.